# Byar's Confidence Interval Calculation

Tags: confidence-interval, python, excel

I was looking for advice on confidence intervals. I am currently working on automating the calculation of some of our indicators using Byar's method (outlined in Formula's 4a and 4b on page 7 of [this document](https://khub.net/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=813cd2f6-de38-4060-b672-2bf14a422fe8&groupId=28021913)). I have coded these formulas out in python and I'm getting to-be-expected results with the following functions:

```
z = 1.96
def byars_lower(count, denominator, rate):
    c = 1 / (9 * count)
    b = 3 * sqrt(count)
    lower_o = count * ((1 - c - (z / b)) ** 3)
    lower_ci = (lower_o / denominator) * rate
    return lower_ci

def byars_higher(count, denominator, rate):
    c = 1 / (9 * (count + 1))
    b = 3 * (sqrt(count) + 1)
    upper_o = (count + 1) * ((1 - c + (z / b)) ** 3)
    upper_ci = (upper_o / denominator) * rate
    return upper_ci
```

The current team practice is to use an excel add-in to generate the CIs that basically have the following formulas:

lower CI = `=IF(A2=0,0,IF(A2<389,CHIINV(0.5+95/200,2*A2)/2,A2*(1-1/(9*A2)-NORMSINV(0.5+95/200)/3/SQRT(A2))^3))/F2*C2`

upper CI = `=IF(A2<389,CHIINV(0.5-95/200,2*A2+2)/2,(A2+1)*(1-1/(9*(A2+1))+NORMSINV(0.5+95/200)/3/SQRT(A2+1))^3)/F2*C2`

where: `A2` = numerator, `F2` = denominator & `C2` = rate

There is a small discrepancy between these two methods that I can't reconcile (0.0005% - 0.001%), and they need to match to pass quality assurance. Would it be due to the `CHIINV` function in the excel formulas that would cause the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some more in depth analysis, there were a few issues:

`z = 1.96` is stated in the documentation, but its actual value should have been `z = ndtri(1 - alpha / 2)` using `from scipy.special import ndtri`.

Line 3 in the `byars_higher` function should read `b = 3 * (sqrt(count + 1))`.

This solves all of the discrepancies for numerators above `389`. I had to put a conditional statement in to deal with the numbers under 389. The `chi2.ppf` function `from scipy.stats import chi2` replicates CHIINV from excel. The if statements are:

```
def byars_lower(count, denominator, rate):
    if count < 389:
        b = (chi2.ppf((alpha * 2), (count * 2)) / 2)
        c = b / denominator
        lower_ci = c * rate
        return lower_ci

def byars_higher(count, denominator, rate):
    if count < 389:
        b = chi2.ppf(1 - (alpha / 2), 2 * count + 2) / 2
        c = b / denominator
        upper_ci = c * rate
        return upper_ci
```

It now replicates the excel function above.